# What is wrong with my C code? Any pointers?

Tags: c

So basically, my C code output is suppose to look like so.

[image]

However I believe my IF statements are incorrect, can someone give it a look and give me some pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, total = 0; // Defining integers
    int n;
    int tax;
    int e;

    float subtotal;

    printf("Enter the number of days the car was rented: "); // Asking for input
    scanf("%d", &n); // Establishing number of cars

    printf("Enter the number of miles the car was driven: "); // Mile input
    scanf("%d", &a); // Establishing miles driven

    if (n > 200) {
        e = .40;
    }
    else { e = .35;
    }

    subtotal = n * 15 + a * e;

    printf("\nSubtotal: ", subtotal);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defined `e` variable is an `int` instead of a floating-point type, like `float` or `double`, **and** you forgot to add the `"%f"` in your last print statement.

To add some more pointers:

- Variables should be given **meaningful** names. I' pretty sure that if you would have changed the name of variable `e` into `precentage`, the above `int`/`float` problem might not have happend.
- All non-used variables should be deleted (`total`, `tax`).

Comment: Thank you and great pointers. I will definitely keep them in mind. Just started using C for my Computer Science course at University, do you think it would be best to follow tutorials / practice or read a book / practice?

Also, I will be using those variables later. I just haven't added the rest of the syntax for them :p

Comment: @Erdowi Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks and will do.

Answer (score 0):

you lost something here：

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, n;
    float tax, e, total = 0; // Defining integers

    float subtotal;

    printf("Enter the number of days the car was rented: "); // Asking for input
    scanf("%d", &n); // Establishing number of cars

    printf("Enter the number of miles the car was driven: "); // Mile input
    scanf("%d", &a); // Establishing miles driven

    if (n > 200) {
        e = .40;
    }
    else { e = .35;
    }

    subtotal = n * 15 + a * e;

    printf("\nSubtotal: %f", subtotal);

}
```

> ```
> gcc filename
> ./a.out
> ```

and here is the result:

```
Enter the number of days the car was rented: 7
Enter the number of miles the car was driven: 7

Subtotal: 107.449997
```

Comment: Thanks or the response, I completely understand now but I'm a little confused about the "gcc filename ./a.out" part.

Comment: I run the code in my linux environment, so I use gcc compiler to compile my c code.     gcc sourcefilename, then it output the default executable file a.out.      then run it with ./a.out

Comment: @Erdowi you can also just run this code on your windows in the devolopment kit.